# Characterization of combinatorial manifolds in terms of links

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-geometry

I need to reference the following result. Do you know a good source?

The following conditions on an $n$-dimensional simplicial complex $S$ are equivalent:
a) $S$ is an $n$ manifold;
b) The link of every vertex of $S$ is homeomorphic to the $(n - 1)$-sphere;
c) The link of every $k$-simplex is homeomorphic to the $(n - k - 1)$-sphere.

Comment: I think this title is a little misleading as the term "simplicial manifold" is usually reserved for a simplicial object in the category of manifolds.

Comment: Changed the title.

Comment: To get a simple correct statement in the category implied by the tags, (a) should refer to S as a combinatorial n-manifold; and (b) and (c) should refer to the links in question as being PL homeomorphic to the appropriate sphere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual term for objects like this is "combinatorial manifolds".

However, the result is not quite true as you have stated.  Definitely b is true if and only if c is true, and b implies a.  However, a does not imply b.  There definitely exist simplicial complexes which do not satisfy b or c but which are topological manifolds.  For example, the famous [double suspension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem) of Cannon (weaker versions were proved by Edwards) says that if $X$ is a homology $n$-sphere, then the space $Y$ obtained by suspending $X$ twice is homeomorphic to the $(n+2)$-sphere.  If neither $X$ nor the suspension of $X$ is an actual sphere (for instance, this holds if $X$ is the [Poincare homology sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere)), the vertices of $Y$ corresponding to the suspension points will then not satisfy b.

Comment: Thanks! I saw an analogous result for homology manifolds and generalized homology spheres, and having heard that b) implies a) guessed that the same should hold.

Comment: One needs to be a little more careful in this mixed category of triangulated topological manifolds. Consideration of the triple suspension of a triangulated homology 3-sphere shows that (b) does not imply (c).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can find this kind of results in 
Rourke and Sanderson's "Introduction to Piecewise linear topology".

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Piecewise-Linear-Ergebnisse-Mathematik-Grenzgebiete/dp/0387111026](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387111026)

Comment: It has parts of the claim as exercises on p. 22 and p. 24.